# Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Setup Failed [0x80240017]- unspecified error

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-7-x64, windows-update

I'm trying to install the Visual C++ 2015 x64 -14.0.23026 package because I'm not able to install photoshop and according to the instructions online I'm supposed to install this package. But I' getting an error when I try to install the package.

Here is my log file. Any help would be appreciated.

```
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i001: Burn v3.7.3813.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\dell\Downloads\vc_redist.x64.exe, cmdline: ''
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170602112922.log'
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\dell\Downloads\vc_redist.x64.exe'
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\dell\Downloads\'
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) - 14.0.23026'
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i100: Detect begin, 10 packages
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKey, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 0
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64 >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT64 = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:22]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i200: Plan begin, 10 packages, action: Install
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170602112922_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64_rollback.log'
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170602112922_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.log'
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170602112922_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64_rollback.log'
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170602112922_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.log'
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:26]i300: Apply begin
[0150:1918][2017-06-02T11:29:28]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0150:1918][2017-06-02T11:29:41]i361: Created a system restore point.
[0150:1918][2017-06-02T11:29:41]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[0150:1918][2017-06-02T11:29:41]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}\.be\VC_redist.x64.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}\VC_redist.x64.exe'
[0150:1918][2017-06-02T11:29:41]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, version: 14.0.23026.0
[0150:1918][2017-06-02T11:29:41]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0150:01B0][2017-06-02T11:29:41]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.
[0150:01B0][2017-06-02T11:29:41]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{0D3E9E15-DE7A-300B-96F1-B4AF12B96488}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi.
[0150:01B0][2017-06-02T11:29:41]i304: Verified existing payload: cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503.
[0150:01B0][2017-06-02T11:29:41]i305: Verified acquired payload: cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{0D3E9E15-DE7A-300B-96F1-B4AF12B96488}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\cab1.cab.
[0150:01B0][2017-06-02T11:29:41]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.
[0150:01B0][2017-06-02T11:29:41]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{BC958BD2-5DAC-3862-BB1A-C1BE0790438D}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi.
[0150:01B0][2017-06-02T11:29:41]i304: Verified existing payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92.
[0150:01B0][2017-06-02T11:29:41]i305: Verified acquired payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{BC958BD2-5DAC-3862-BB1A-C1BE0790438D}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\cab1.cab.
[0150:01B0][2017-06-02T11:29:41]i304: Verified existing payload: Windows7_MSU_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Windows7_MSU_x64.
[0150:01B0][2017-06-02T11:29:41]i305: Verified acquired payload: Windows7_MSU_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Windows7_MSU_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\42D5BEC7DDFBD49E76467529CBC2868987BF8460\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu.
[0150:1918][2017-06-02T11:29:41]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{0D3E9E15-DE7A-300B-96F1-B4AF12B96488}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:45]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0150:1918][2017-06-02T11:29:45]i325: Registering dependency: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_amd64,v14, package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64
[0150:1918][2017-06-02T11:29:45]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{BC958BD2-5DAC-3862-BB1A-C1BE0790438D}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:49]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0150:1918][2017-06-02T11:29:49]i325: Registering dependency: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_amd64,v14, package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64
[0150:1918][2017-06-02T11:29:49]i301: Applying execute package: Windows7_MSU_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\42D5BEC7DDFBD49E76467529CBC2868987BF8460\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu, arguments: '"C:\Windows\SysNative\wusa.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\42D5BEC7DDFBD49E76467529CBC2868987BF8460\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart'
[0150:1918][2017-06-02T11:29:52]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:52]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:52]i319: Applied execute package: Windows7_MSU_x64, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:52]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[0150:1918][2017-06-02T11:29:52]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[0150:1918][2017-06-02T11:29:52]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[1648:1B88][2017-06-02T11:29:52]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80240017, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: This has very little to do with the C++ language. Please consider removing the C++ tag. Please consult the Visual C++ redistributable vendor.

Answer (score 4):

Anyone still running into this error. Here is a solution;

it's probably the file in:
C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\FC6260C33678BB17FB8B88536C476B4015B7C5E9\packages\Patch\x64
called:
Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu.
You can install it manually. Just open up command prompt as admin and do:

```
c:
mkdir tmp
mkdir tmp\tmp
```

Now you should have that tmp\tmp folders in C: drive. Now minimize cmd because we are going to need that again and just copy and paste the file from `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\FC6260C33678BB17FB8B88536C476B4015B7C5E9\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu` and paste it to `C:\tmp` < first level not the inner tmp. Then go back to cmd again and type the following:

```
expand -F:* c:\tmp\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu c:\tmp\tmp
```

Then

```
dism /online /add-package /packagepath:c:\tmp\tmp\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.cab
```

And try to reinstall the Visual C++ it should install without any problem this time.

Comment: Wow, that totally saved my life.

Comment: Thanks a lot Man... It's perfect. Just add "dism /online /add-package /packagepath:c:\tmp\tmp\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.cab" as next command to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Unstall Visual C++ completely:

[image]

Install the windows updates

[image]

Try to reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Updated the above solution as Bat file.

```
Rem To run: Run command prompt as admin
Rem Bat file name "Path of the msu exe"
Rem Example VC_fix.bat "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3ACBF3890FC9C8A6F3D2155ECF106028E5F55164\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu"
cd \
mkdir tmp\tmp
xcopy %1 C:\tmp
expand -F:* c:\tmp\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu c:\tmp\tmp
dism /online /add-package /packagepath:c:\tmp\tmp\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.cab
```

Save the above code as VC_fix.bat and do the below steps

1. Run command prompt as admin
2. Pass the msu file path as parameters to run.

***Example***: **VC_fix.bat "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3ACBF3890FC9C8A6F3D2155ECF106028E5F55164\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu"**

3. Run the Visual C++ setup again.

This time setup will be successful.